# dateformatter works in simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, device, nsdateformatter

this code works on simulator ... but not on my ipod touch... on ipod I see the unformated date :-(

```
 NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] retain];
```

//Date Before = Sun, 20 Jun 2010 06:00:00 +020

```
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
        NSDate *d = [formatter dateFromString:string];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"];
        string = [NSString stringWithString:[formatter stringFromDate:d]];
        [currentDate appendString:string];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the device, you need to explicitly set your locale.

Insert this line:

```
[formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
```

Right after:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
```